# Showing a footer on some pages

Tags: html, css, footer

I am using the following:

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
     div#print-footer {display: none;}
</style>
<style type="text/css" media="print">
     div#print-footer {display: block; position: fixed; bottom: 0;}
</style>
```

the div for the footer is:

```
<div id="print-footer"><p>blah blah</p></div>
```

It works great but since I have multiple pages it print on every page. I want it on some pages. Oy! So, I broke the pages into individual html documents and that didn't work either. Then on even pages I changed the div to be:

```
<div id="print-footer">&nbsp;</div>
```

but it ignored it and printed the first one.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Evan

Comment: If you have multiple such divs per HTML page you need to use `class="print-footer"` and not `id="print-footer"`.

Comment: Strange. Now that I changed it to class=... I get a double footer. Two at the bottom of odd pages and one at even pages. In the pages where the double appears, one is a footer and the other appears at the end of the content (about the middle of the page).

Comment: as BoltClock said you would use class to define multiple div's with the same css. Id is for defining an individual div.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't quite understand css. How would I have a page or more without the footer?

Comment: I reduced the code to the absolute minimum and using the latest Firefox   I get double footers:

Comment: Oops. I forgot to add the code: 
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
div#print-footer {display: none;}
</style>
<style type="text/css" media="print">
div#print-footer {display: block; position: fixed; bottom: 0;}
</style></head>
<style type="text/css">
p.breakhere {page-break-before: always}
</style>

<body>
<tableborder=1>
<tr><td colspan=9><h4>data here</td></tr>
</table>
<div id="print-footer"><p align=center>footer</p></div>
<p class="breakhere">&nbsp;</p>
</body>
</html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<p>address here - no footer needed</p>
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 1):

An element that has position:fixed will be rendered on every printed page. See: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/position

If you don't want the footer to appear on every printed page, use absolute positioning with bottom:0

Comment: I made this change and if I use class= the footer appears after the content. If I use id= the the footer appears correctly but only in the first page. All other pages do not have the footer.

Comment: I'm using footer inside <table>, so position: absolute didn't work for me, but removing position: fixed, worked like a charm, unfortunately on pages where there is not enough content footer doesn't appear at the bottom